# Jersey 2.x Custom Injection Annotation With Attributes

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, dropwizard, hk2

I am in the process of migrating from DropWizard 0.7.1 to 0.8.1. This includes migrating from Jersey 1.x to 2.x. In my
implementation that uses Jersey 1.18.1, I had a `MyProvider` (changed all class names for simplicity's sake) that implements `InjectableProvider`. This
class would create `MyInjectable` objects, containing the custom injection annotation, `MyToken`. `MyToken` contains various attributes
that are passed on and read by `MyInjectable`. Lastly, in the `Application` class I register a new instance of `MyProvider`, as seen below.

I've done some research and can't seem to wrap my head around on how I'd recreate (or replace, I suppose) such a secenario in Jersey 2.x.

Here is the current, 1.18.1 implementation:

```
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target({ ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD })
    public @interface MyToken {

        // Custom annotation containing various attributes
        boolean someAttribute() default true;
        // ...
    }

    public class MyProvider implements InjectableProvider<MyToken, Parameter> {

        // io.dropwizard.auth.Authenticator
        private final Authenticator<String, MyObject> authenticator;

        public MyProvider(Authenticator<String, MyObject> authenticator) {
            this.authenticator = authenticator;
        }

        @Override
        public ComponentScope getScope() {
            return ComponentScope.PerRequest;
        }

        @Override
        public Injectable<?> getInjectable(ComponentContext ic, MyToken t, Parameter p) {
            return new MyInjectable(authenticator, t.someAttribute());      
        }
    }

    class MyInjectable extends AbstractHttpContextInjectable<MyObject> {
        private final Authenticator<String, Session> authenticator;
        private final boolean someAttribute;

        public MyInjectable(Authenticator<String, MyObject> authenticator, boolean someAttribute) {
            this.authenticator = authenticator;
            this.someAttribute = someAttribute;
            // ... Removed a few paramters for simplicity's sake
        }

        @Override
        public MyObject getValue(HttpContext c) {
            final HttpRequestContext request = c.getRequest();
            // ... Removed code not pertaining to the question
            return myObject;
        }
    }

// Lastly, the register call in the io.dropwizard.Application class
environment.jersey().register(new MyProvider(new MyProviderValidator(someValidator)));
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yeah Jersey made the creation of custom injections a bit more complicated in 2.x. There are a few main components to custom injection you need to know about with Jersey 2.x

- [`org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory`](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/Factory.html) - Creates injectable objects/services
- [`org.glassfish.hk2.api.InjectionResolver`](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/InjectionResolver.html) - Used to create injection points for your own annotations.
- [`org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ValueFactoryProvider`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server/2.6/org/glassfish/jersey/server/spi/internal/ValueFactoryProvider.html) - To provide parameter value injections.

You can read more about custom injection in [Custom Injection and Lifecycle Management](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/ioc.html). One shortcoming of the documentation is the lack of explanation of how to inject parameter values. You could get away with simply implementing the `InjectResolver`, and you would be able to inject into fields with your custom annotation, but in order to inject into method parameters, we need to `ValueFactoryProvider`.

Luckily there are some abstract classes we can extend (which the documentation also fails to mention) that will make life a little easier. I has to scour the [source code of the `org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject` package](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/internal/inject) for a bit to try and figure it all out.

Here's a full example to help get you started.

**`Token`** (injectable object)

```
public class Token {
    private final String token;
    public Token(String token) { this.token = token; }
    public String getToken() { return token; }
}
```

**`@TokenParam`** (our injection annotation)

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface TokenParam {
    boolean someAttribute() default true;
}
```

**`TokenFactory`** (implements `Factory` per the first bullet point, but we just extend the `AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory`. There we'll have access to the `ContainerRequestContext`. Note, that all these HK2 components, we can inject other dependencies into them, for example the `TokenAuthenticator`, which we will bind to HK2 later.

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory;

public class TokenFactory extends AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory<Token> {
    
    private final TokenAuthenticator tokenAuthenticator;
    
    @Inject
    public TokenFactory(TokenAuthenticator tokenAuthenticator) {
        this.tokenAuthenticator = tokenAuthenticator;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Token provide() {
        String auth = getContainerRequest().getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        try {
            if (tokenAuthenticator.authenticate(auth).get() == null) {
                throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN);
            }
        } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TokenFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        return new Token("New Token");
    }  
}
```

**`TokenParamInjectionResolver`** (implements the `InjectResolver` per bullet point two. I simply extend `ParamInjectionResolver`. If your interested in what's going on under the hood, you can find the class in the source code I linked to)

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.ParamInjectionResolver;

public class TokenParamInjectionResolver extends ParamInjectionResolver {
    public TokenParamInjectionResolver() {
        super(TokenFactoryProvider.class);
    }
}
```

**`TokenFactoryProvider`** (implements the `ValueFactoryProvider` per the third bullet point. I simply extend `AbstractValueFactoryProvider`. Again, you can look at the source for the under the hood details)

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractValueFactoryProvider;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.MultivaluedParameterExtractorProvider;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Parameter;

public class TokenFactoryProvider extends AbstractValueFactoryProvider {
    
    private final TokenFactory tokenFactory;
    
    @Inject
    public TokenFactoryProvider(
            final MultivaluedParameterExtractorProvider extractorProvider,
            ServiceLocator locator,
            TokenFactory tokenFactory) {
        
        super(extractorProvider, locator, Parameter.Source.UNKNOWN);
        this.tokenFactory = tokenFactory;
    }

    @Override
    protected Factory<?> createValueFactory(Parameter parameter) {
         Class<?> paramType = parameter.getRawType();
         TokenParam annotation = parameter.getAnnotation(TokenParam.class);
         if (annotation != null && paramType.isAssignableFrom(Token.class)) {
             return tokenFactory;
         }
         return null;
    }
}
```

**`TokenFeature`** (Here we bind all the components seen above, even the `TokenAuthentictor`, which I have left out, but if your usual Dropwizard `Authenticator`. I also made use of a `Feature`. I tend to do this to wrap components of a custom feature. This is also where you can decide all the scoping. Just note some components are required to be in `Singleton` scope)

```
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Feature;
import javax.ws.rs.core.FeatureContext;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.InjectionResolver;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.TypeLiteral;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ValueFactoryProvider;

public class TokenFeature implements Feature {

    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        context.register(new AbstractBinder(){
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                bind(TokenAuthenticator.class)
                        .to(TokenAuthenticator.class)
                        .in(Singleton.class);
                bind(TokenFactory.class).to(TokenFactory.class)
                        .in(Singleton.class);
                bind(TokenFactoryProvider.class)
                        .to(ValueFactoryProvider.class)
                        .in(Singleton.class);
                bind(TokenParamInjectionResolver.class)
                        .to(new TypeLiteral<InjectionResolver<TokenParam>>(){})
                        .in(Singleton.class);
            }
        });
        return true;
    } 
}
```

And finally simply register the feature

```
register(TokenFeature.class);
```

Now you should be able to inject the `Token` with `@TokenParam`, as well as your usual entity bodies (which would not be possible if we didn't implement the `ValueFactoryProvider`

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String postToken(@TokenParam Token token, User user) {
    
}
```

---

### UPDATE

It's kind of a half-@$$ example for your particular use case. A better approach would probably have a clone method in your `Factory` class and create a new `TokenFactory` with some parameters (maybe that you get from your annotation`. For example, in the` TokenFactory` you can have something like

```
public class TokenFactory extends AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory<Token> {

    public TokenFactory clone(boolean someAttribute) {
        return new TokenFactory(authenticator, someAttribute);
    }
```

In the `TokenFactoryProvider` ine `createValueFactory` method, you then call the clone method

```
TokenParam annotation = parameter.getAnnotation(TokenParam.class);

if (annotation != null && paramType.isAssignableFrom(Token.class)) {
    return tokenFactory.clone(annotation.someAttribute());
}
```

Or you could actually *create* the factory inside the method. you have options.

### UPDATE 2

**See Also**

- [jersey 2 context injection based upon HttpRequest without singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34747574/2587435)

### UPDATE 3

Starting Jersey 2.26, the dependency injection has changed. You will want to look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50975973/2587435) for example of how the code has changed in implementing this same injection.

Comment: You deleted your comments on my other question, so I'll ask here. Since I'm trying to inject a field onto an `@BeanParam`, is that why I need the `ValueFactoryProvider`? Because from the documentation around the `InjectionResolver`, I got the strong implication that it would be sufficient to inject a field onto a BeanParam, since it is a standalone object. Regardless, thanks for the help and I'm going to try the Value Factory widget.

Comment: @PatrickM I deleted because I was unsure (I didn't do any testing and have never tried to inject in to a @BeanParam bean). But for method parameters it appears we need to use `ValueFactoryProvider`. It seems the `InjectionResolver` is not enough. Since it seems to apply to method params, I though it might apply to your bean fields also. I may be wrong, but doesn't hurt to give it a shot.

Comment: I found this answer to be quite useful but also a bit confusing. I tried getting it to work, but was always greated with "No injection source found for a parameter" errors. I Followed the jersey source example of https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/927b4d0605aeb119d15e9623dab65c8aec2c8e20/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/internal/inject/HeaderParamValueFactoryProvider.java  I also made an example project: https://github.com/evadnoob/jersey2-method-param-injection

Comment: Is it possible to inject with @Context annotation? I cannot get it working. I do exact stuff you've described except for Resolver, since ContextInjectionResolver is already configured by jersey framework