# Authorize User in Spring/Jersey

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security, jersey, jersey-2.0

I'm working in a Spring/Jersey setup and trying to figure out how to authorize a user to access only resources that belong to them.  I've seen numerous examples of how to secure an endpoint using authorization or broad role-based security, but I haven't seen anything that makes sure the user submitting the request is submitting it for his/her own stuff.

For clarity, suppose I have a GET /account/1 endpoint.  I want only the user with ID 1 to be able to access that account information and only once he/she is authenticated.  I've got the latter part taken care of using OAuth, but I can't figure out the former part.

How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Spring Security's [`SecurityContext`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContext.html) is [a thread local](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/context/ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy.java#L34). So you can access it anywhere from the request thread, using the [`SecurityContextHolder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html). From the `SecurityContext` you can obtain the `UserDetails`, which will have the user name.

So because the Jersey request processing occurs in the same request thread, you should be able to access this information. From a Jersey component you can use whatever service you want to obtain you actual user domain objects and just check for the same user. For example you can have something like

```
@Path("/accounts")
public class AccountsResource {

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public User get(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        User user = userService.getUser(id);
        // if user == null throw 404

        UserDetails userDetails
                = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (!userDetails.getUsername().equals(user.getUsername())) {
            throw new ForbiddenException();
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

If you have a lot of endpoints like this, and you want to keep it DRY, you can use a Jersey filter to handle the access control process.

```
@Provider
@AccessFiltered
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION)
public class UserAccessFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        List<String> params = requestContext.getUriInfo().getPathParameters().get("id");
        Long id = Long.parseLong(params.get(0));
        User user = userService.getUser(id);
        // if user == null throw 404

        UserDetails userDetails
                = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (!userDetails.getUsername().equals(user.getUsername())) {
            throw new ForbiddenException();
        }
    }
}
```

Now with the [Name Binding Annotation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9916) `@AccessFiltered`

```
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface AccessFiltered {
}
```

We can just filter the methods we annotated

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@AccessFiltered
@Produces("application/json")
public User get(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
}
```

Now suppose we want access to that `User`, and we don't want to have to hit the DB again to retrieve it in our resource method. It's possible to put the `User` we obtained inside the filter, into the request context ([a full example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27666797/2587435))

```
public class UserAccessFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    public static final String USER_FILTER_PROPERTY = "UserAccessFilter.User";

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        ...
        User user = userService.getUser(id);
        ...
        requestContext.setProperty(USER_FILTER_PROPERTY, user);
    }
}
```

Then we can just inject the `User` into our resource method

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@AccessFiltered
@Produces("application/json")
public User get(@Context User user) {
    return user;
}
```

There's one more step to configure this (i.e. the `Factory` - see the previous link). You could also [create a custom annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30426226/2587435) for injecting the user, but that gets a bit more complicated.

I'm sure this type of access control could be implemented using Spring Security's ACL feature, but for me being a Jersey user, this way is more intuitive for me.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed response!!  I can't wait to try this when I get home :-)

Comment: Good sir, I owe you a beer.  Thanks for your great answer and explanation!!