# Inject SecurityContext info and Request Body into @BeanParam

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

Currently I'm rendering a command object in a `MessageBodyReader` but I'd like to be able to do this in a `@BeanParam`:

1. Inject a field derived from the `SecurityContext` (Is there somewhere to hook in the conversion?).
2. have a field inject that has been materialised by a `MessageBodyReader`.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: Go Down to UPDATE. I guess it *is* possible to use `@BeanParam`. Though you need to inject the `SecurityContext` into the bean and extract the name info.**

---

<s>There's no way to achieve this with `@BeanParam`</s> <sup>corrected</sup>. You *could* use a `MessageBodyReader` the way you are doing, but IMO that's more of a hack than anything. Instead, the way I would achieve it is to use the framework components the way they are supposed to be used, which involves custom parameter injection.

To achieve this, you need two things, a `ValueFactoryProvider` to provide parameter values, and a `InjectionResolver` with your own custom annotation. I won't do much explaining for the example below, but you can find a good explanation in

- [Jersey 2.x Custom Injection Annotation With Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30397933/2587435)

You can run the below example like any JUnit test. Everything is included into the one class. These are the dependencies I used.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And here is the test

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.security.Principal;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.PreMatching;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.InjectionResolver;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.TypeLiteral;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractValueFactoryProvider;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.MultivaluedParameterExtractorProvider;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.ParamInjectionResolver;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Parameter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ValueFactoryProvider;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CustomInjectionTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public static @interface CustomParam {
    }

    public static class CustomModel {

        public String name;
        public RequestBody body;
    }

    public static class RequestBody {

        public String message;
    }

    public static class CustomParamValueFactory
            extends AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory<CustomModel> {

        @Override
        public CustomModel provide() {
            ContainerRequest request = getContainerRequest();
            String name = request.getSecurityContext().getUserPrincipal().getName();
            RequestBody body = request.readEntity(RequestBody.class);
            CustomModel model = new CustomModel();
            model.body = body;
            model.name = name;
            return model;
        }
    }
    
    public static class CustomValueFactoryProvider extends AbstractValueFactoryProvider {
        
        @Inject
        public CustomValueFactoryProvider(MultivaluedParameterExtractorProvider multiProvider,
                                          ServiceLocator locator) {
            super(multiProvider, locator, Parameter.Source.UNKNOWN);
        }

        @Override
        protected Factory<?> createValueFactory(Parameter parameter) {
            if (CustomModel.class == parameter.getType()
                    && parameter.isAnnotationPresent(CustomParam.class)) {
                return new CustomParamValueFactory();
            }
            return null;
        }  
    }
    
    public static class CustomParamInjectionResolver extends ParamInjectionResolver<CustomParam> {
        
        public CustomParamInjectionResolver() {
            super(CustomValueFactoryProvider.class);
        }
    }
    
    private static class CustomInjectBinder extends AbstractBinder {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(CustomValueFactoryProvider.class)
                    .to(ValueFactoryProvider.class)
                    .in(Singleton.class);
            bind(CustomParamInjectionResolver.class)
                    .to(new TypeLiteral<InjectionResolver<CustomParam>>(){})
                    .in(Singleton.class);
        } 
    }
    
    private static final String PRINCIPAL_NAME = "peeskillet";
    
    @PreMatching
    public static class SecurityContextFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

        @Override
        public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
            requestContext.setSecurityContext(new SecurityContext(){
                public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
                    return new Principal() { 
                        public String getName() { return PRINCIPAL_NAME; }
                    };
                }
                public boolean isUserInRole(String role) { return false; }
                public boolean isSecure() { return true;}
                public String getAuthenticationScheme() { return null; }
            });   
        }  
    }
    
    @Path("test")
    public static class TestResource {
        @POST
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public String post(@CustomParam CustomModel model) {
            return model.name + ":" + model.body.message;
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(TestResource.class)
                .register(SecurityContextFilter.class)
                .register(new CustomInjectBinder());
    }
    
    @Test
    public void should_return_name_with_body() {
        RequestBody body = new RequestBody();
        body.message = "Hello World";
        Response response = target("test").request()
                .post(Entity.json(body));
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        String responseBody = response.readEntity(String.class);
        assertEquals(PRINCIPAL_NAME + ":" + body.message, responseBody);
        System.out.println(responseBody);
    }
}
```

Note that I read the request body from the `ContainerRequest` inside the `CustomParamValueFactory`. It is the same `RequestBody` that I sent in JSON from the request in the `@Test`.

---

#### UPDATE

So to my surprise, it *is* possible to use `@BeanParam`. Here is the following bean I used to test

```
public static class CustomModel {

    @Context
    public SecurityContext securityContext;
    public RequestBody body;
}

public static class RequestBody {

    public String message;
}
```

The difference from the previous test is that instead of the `name` from the `SecurityContext.Principal`, we need to inject the entire `SecurityContext`. There's just no way for the inject to get the name from the `Principal`, So we will just do it manually.

The thing that surprised me the most though, is that we are able to inject the `RequestBody` entity. I didn't know this was possible.

Here is the complete test

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Principal;
import javax.ws.rs.BeanParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.PreMatching;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CustomInjectTestTake2 extends JerseyTest {
    
    private static final String PRINCIPAL_NAME = "peeskillet";
    private static final String MESSAGE = "Hello World";
    private static final String RESPONSE = PRINCIPAL_NAME + ":" + MESSAGE;
    
    public static class CustomModel {

        @Context
        public SecurityContext securityContext;
        public RequestBody body;
    }

    public static class RequestBody {

        public String message;
    }
    
    @PreMatching
    public static class SecurityContextFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

        @Override
        public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
            requestContext.setSecurityContext(new SecurityContext(){
                public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
                    return new Principal() { 
                        public String getName() { return PRINCIPAL_NAME; }
                    };
                }
                public boolean isUserInRole(String role) { return false; }
                public boolean isSecure() { return true;}
                public String getAuthenticationScheme() { return null; }
            });   
        }  
    }
    
    @Path("test")
    public static class TestResource {
        @POST
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public String post(@BeanParam CustomModel model) {
            return model.securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName() 
                    + ":"  + model.body.message;
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(TestResource.class)
                .register(SecurityContextFilter.class);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void should_return_name_with_body() {
        RequestBody body = new RequestBody();
        body.message = "Hello World";
        Response response = target("test").request()
                .post(Entity.json(body));
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        String responseBody = response.readEntity(String.class);
        assertEquals(RESPONSE, responseBody);
        System.out.println(responseBody);
    }
}
```

**See Also:**

- [Custom Injection and Lifecycle Management](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html)

Comment: Many thanks for the setting me straight :D I was originally going to use this approach (2 weeks ago) but I was quite early in the skilling up phase at the time and it seemed like a tangent or over-engineering with the possibility of me finding a more appropriate solution.

Comment: Yeah it does seem like a bit much, but this is actually how Jersey handles all of the `@BeanParam`, `@FormParam`, `@PathParam`, etc. So we could follow this pattern... or not :-)

Comment: @HassanSyed Please see my UPDATE. I guess it _is_ possible with `@BeanParam` :-)

Comment: Having a body in a BeanParam annotated class didn't work for me. body is not mapped; always null.