# What is replacement of com.sun.jersey.api.core.InjectParam in Jersey2

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

I am migrating a project from Jersey 1.8 to 2.23.2.I have found following replacements till now :

In RestService :

```
1)com.sun.jersey.core.header.ContentDisposition to org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.ContentDisposition
2)com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataBodyPart     to org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataBodyPart
3)com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart    to org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart
```

In Web.xml :

```
1)com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet to org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
2)com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages                   to jersey.config.server.provider.packages
3)com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature                to org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature
```

However I am not able to find how can I achieve dependency injection with jersey2.Earlier we were using com.sun.jersey.api.core.InjectParam like below :

```
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {

   /*@InjectParam
    private SomeService someService;*/
}
```

Can anyone please suggest ,how this can be done in Jersey2 in simplest way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397933/jersey-2-x-custom-injection-annotation-with-attributes what you are after?

Comment: Thanks for your response.This looks like too much for making dependency injection to work.I did not get it completely. Don't we simply have some replacement for com.sun.jersey.api.core.InjectParam.