# JAX-RS @Context usage in Jersey 2 compared to Jersey 1

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, hk2

[EDIT] *The problem is with the 
register(new ServiceBinder<>(MyService.class));
Jersey generates a warning and ignores the registration for all but the first one (Existing previous registration found for the type); it only considers the type-erased ServiceBinder class to decide there is a conflict.
It looks like I need to use a more sophisticated version of register to get past that issue.*
[/EDIT]

In Jersey 1 I was able to use custom injectable providers to inject my objects into both class fields and method parameters, by extending
LazySingletonInjectableProvider

I can't figure out how to port that pattern to Jersey 2 (with hk2 on Tomcat 7). I have read everything I could find on the topic, including [Jersey custom method parameter injection with inbuild injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145807/jersey-custom-method-parameter-injection-with-inbuild-injection) - but I don't want to use a custom annotation, and I am not trying to inject a request parameter.

[EDIT] I made the wrong assumption regarding what works and what doesn't:

- Injection into a class field in a ContainerRequestFilter works fine
- Injection into a resource, either as class field or method parameter does not work

[EDIT 2]: The InjectionResolver as described below actually doesn't work at all, I have removed it. Jersey already has a ContextInjectionResolver which presumably should take care of the @Context annotation.

I have created and registered an AbstractBinder, <strike>and with that class field injection works fine; however method parameter injection doesn't (the binder never gets invoked and the parameter remains null).</strike>
I have tried to bind an InjectionResolver but that didn't help either.

Any suggestion on how to make this work would be greatly appreciated... here is the current code:

## The HK2 binder:

```
public class ServiceBinder<T> extends AbstractBinder
{
    private final Factory<T> _factory;
    private final Class<? extends T> _clazz;

    public OsgiServiceBinder(Class<T> clazz)
    {
        _factory = new ServiceFactory<>(clazz);
        _clazz = clazz;
    }

    protected void configure()
    {
        bindFactory(_factory).to(_clazz); //.in(RequestScoped.class);
        bind(ServiceInjectionResolver.class)
            .to(new TypeLiteral<InjectionResolver<Context>>() { })
            .in(PerLookup.class);
    }
}
```

## The injection resolver:

```
public class ServiceInjectionResolver<T> implements InjectionResolver<Context>
{
    private Class<T> _clazz;

    public OsgiServiceInjectionResolver(Class<T> clazz)
    {
        _clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Object resolve(Injectee injectee, ServiceHandle<?> root)
    {
        if (_clazz.getCanonicalName().equals(injectee.getRequiredType().getTypeName())) {
            return Framework.getService(_clazz);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isConstructorParameterIndicator()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isMethodParameterIndicator()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

## The JAX-RS registration:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    public MyApplication()
    {
        registerClasses(<resource classes>);
        register(new ServiceBinder<>(MyService.class));
    }
}
```

## The resource class:

```
   @Path("/schedules")
public class SchedulesResource
{
    @Context UriInfo _uriInfo;

    // This injection works fine, _service1 is properly initialized
    @Context MyService _service1;

    @PUT
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Path("{jobGroup}/{jobName}")
    public Response putSchedule(@Context MyService service2,
                                ...)
    {
        // The injection of service2 doesn't work...
    }
}
```

## The Factory class:

```
public class ServiceFactory<T> implements Factory<T>
{
    private Class<T> _clazz;

    protected ServiceFactory(Class<T> clazz)
    {
       _clazz = clazz;
    }

    public T provide()
    {
        return Framework.getService(_clazz);
    }
}

public void dispose(T t)
{
}
```

}

pok

Comment: I updated the post with the Factory. Thanks for the link, this is hinting at having to bind with a Request scope.
I tried that at some point and injection broke in the filters, as described in the link you provided. I assumed that PerLookup scope would work in all cases, but maybe Jersey only considers Request scope for Resource injection?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Can you provide a (single class) test case like below (with a failing test). I will delete it once you edit your question.

Comment: As an aside, if the request scoped worked for you but failed just in the filters, you should inject `javax.inject.Provider<MyService> myServiceProvider`, instead of `MyService`. Then when you need the service, call `myServiceProvider.get()`. This lazily loads the service so that it can work in wider scopes.

Comment: The problem with the filters is in fact that hk2 refuses to do the injection because the binding is RequestScoped. I am getting this exception: 
org.glassfish.hk2.api.MultiException: A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not inside a request scope.
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.fico.dmp.rest.filters.FileKeyResponseFilter errors were found
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.fico.dmp.rest.filters.FileKeyResponseFilter

Comment: See my above comment for injecting into the filter

Comment: Stupid mistake with binder registration actually... thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually with Jersey component registrations.
Even though I was registering binder instances, Jersey was checking the class (ServiceBinder) and discarding all but the first registration (WARN: existing registration found for the type).

This seems a bit bogus given I am registering instances, and I wish Jersey would fail with an error rather than log a warning when failing to register a component, but the solution is to simply change the registration pattern slightly:

```
// Doesn't work
 register(new ServiceBinder<>(MyService1.class));
 register(new ServiceBinder<>(MyService2.class));

// Works like a charm
register(new ServiceBinder(MyService1.class, MyService2.class));
```

where obviously the ServiceBinder is adjusted to call bindFactory for each supplied service.